# Sql Left Join Error

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, left-join

hello i have a question about left join. I have two tables "Customer", "Meeting" and common column is "mkod".

Customers table has "mkod" and "customername" colums
Meeting table has "mkod", "details" and "meetingdate"

i want to see all the records from customers and "details" column on mkod and the last meeting date from meeting table.

but i can not see all records on meeting.

My code is like that,

```
select c.mkod,m.details 
from customer c 
left join meeting m on c.mkod=m.mkod 
where m.details=
    (select top 1 details 
    from meeting 
    where c.mkod=meeting.mkod 
    order by meetingdate desc) 
order by c.mkod
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT c.mkod, IFNULL(m.details, '') AS details
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.mkod, m.details
           FROM meeting m 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mkod, MAX(m.meetingdate) meetingdate 
                       FROM meeting m 
                       GROUP BY m.mkod
                     ) a ON m.mkod = a.mkod AND m.meetingdate = a.meetingdate 
         ) m ON c.mkod=m.mkod;
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT c.mkod, ISNULL(m.details, '') AS details
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.mkod, m.details
           FROM meeting m 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mkod, MAX(m.meetingdate) meetingdate 
                       FROM meeting m 
                       GROUP BY m.mkod
                     ) a ON m.mkod = a.mkod AND m.meetingdate = a.meetingdate 
         ) m ON c.mkod=m.mkod;
```

Comment: thank you it works, but one more thing, on the result table if no data in details column, it types NULL, can it be blank rather then NULL.

Comment: i have tried this code but no actions,   select c.mkod, case m.details when NULL then ' ' when m.details then m.details end from........     thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select c.mkod, m.details
from customer c left join
     meeting m
     on c.mkod=m.mkod
where m.details=(select top 1 details from meeting where c.mkod=meeting.mkod order by meetingdate desc)
order by c.mkod;
```

The `where` clause has a condition on the second table in a `left outer join`.  That means that the condition will not return true when the column values are `NULL` -- turning the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.  You can fix this by moving the condition to the `on` clause:

```
select c.mkod, m.details
from customer c left join
     meeting m
     on c.mkod = m.mkod and
        m.details = (select top 1 m2.details from meeting m2 where c.mkod = m2.mkod order by m2.meetingdate desc)
order by c.mkod;
```

Also, if you want the most recent, shouldn't the condition be on `meetingdate` rather than `details`?

```
select c.mkod, m.details
from customer c left join
     meeting m
     on c.mkod = m.mkod and
        m.meetingdate = (select max(m2.meetingdate) from meeting m2 where c.mkod = m2.mkod)
order by c.mkod;
```